# Help using cumulative kronecker product notation in LaTeX?

Tags: amsmath

I am trying to recreate this notation for a cumulative kronecker product in LaTeX. Discussed in math.stackexchange at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800661/how-to-simplify-notation-for-the-kronecker-product-of-multiple-matrices#comment5774051_2800661

[image: Notation for cumulative kronecker product]

So far my research has turned up the \otimes command, but I would ideally like to come up with a command  similar to the \sum and \product commands.

Many sincere thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope to understand your request: `\bigotimes` is a big symbol instead of `\otimes` and it is possible to use also in **mathjax** that is a subset of `LaTeX`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document} 

\[\bigotimes_{i = 1}^{n} A_i,  \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{i}, \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_{i}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was completely unaware of the \bigotimes command. It appears to be the solution to the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @mykhaylo You're welcome and all the best....